# Compare two excel files to change elements in cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison, headers

I have two excel files, A and B.

A is a dataframe with a header.

B has two columns, the first one has the original name and the second one has new name

A:

```
    sam1 sam2 sam3 sam4 ....
p1  0    1    2    1
p2  2    3    3    4
p3  5    6    1    2 
....
```

B:

```
sam1 newname1
sam2 newname2
sam3 newname3
sam4 newname4
....
```

I want to change the header of A for "newnames" in B.

So the output will be

A':

```
     newname1 newname2 newname3 newname4 ....
p1  0         1        2        1
p2  2         3        3        4
p3  5         6        1        2 
....
```

Note that B can have more "original name - newname" rows than the number of headers in A.
So the comparison is only done with names in the headers in A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these formulas:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,$A$8:$B$11,2,0)
```

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A15=$A$3:$A$5)*(B$2=$B$2:$E$2),$B$3:$E$5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked well!